# What is the best way to reuse an Android layout with minor variations?

Tags: android

I have a layout that I reuse frequently with `<include>` that contains a `TextView`. I need to use a different font size in different places that it's included. Setting it in Java/Kotlin when I inflate the layout feels like a heavy solution. Is there an XML-only solution that will accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK no . Setting it at runtime seems only solution . instead of setting text size you can make different styles for each type and just change only style at runtime . all attributes will reflect on the view .

Comment: If you introduce [a custom View](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view) (which will be the ViewGroup from your layout), you can declare and set your own attributes in xml. Of course you will have to set up a whole new class but on the other hand you will have less boilerplate code every time you inflate the layout.

Comment: Yes, I ended up creating a custom view with custom attributes. Seemed excessive at the time but it worked out really well.